# AWS API Gateway. Lambda Proxy Integration on entry point Resource to manipulate data and then forward to all subsequent resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to create a main entry point resource connected to a lambda function (Lambda Proxy Integration with a Proxy Resource) that manipulates the request data (header/body etc) and then forwards the response to the next resource.

Example

1. /api/ => Call lambda function (Lambda Proxy Integration with a Proxy Resource)
2. Manipulate the request data and let it pass to the next resource (if defined)
3. /api/car => (Lambda Integration) handle the data for this specific resource but also retrieve the extra data added on /api/

Guessing I want the /api/ main resource to work as a central gateway that adds needed data that is passed to all other resource endpoints so that I dont need to fetch the data on each endpoint all the time.

Hope it makes sense...

Comment: have you looked at https://www.zappa.io/ ?

Comment: Not sure it solves the issue. Looking for a central entry point that can add extra data and pass it forward to the other resource rest end points.